# Yii2: How to create pages dynamically using mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I have `roomcatalogue.php` page, this page shows all available rooms to choose from-

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key=>$row): ?>
<!-- Item -->
<div class="col-sm-6 masonry-item">
<a href="<?php echo Url::to(['site/roompage']); ?>" class="product_item text-center">
<span class="product_photo bordered_wht_border">
    <img src="images/rooms/double_room.jpg" alt=""> 
</span>
<span class="product_title"><?php echo $row['room_type']; ?></span>
<span class="product_price">Rs.<?php echo $row['rate']; ?></span>

</a>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also I have `roompage.php` which will holds all the room description/information regarding room.

I need `roompage.php` should change according to room, when user will click on particular room from `roomcatalogue.php`.

Question may sound basic I tried with many tutorials stating to use `$_GET[]` method but im not able to use it properly please help regarding this.

**UPDATE**

```
public function actionRoompage($id)
    {
        $searchModel = new RoomTypesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $data = RoomTypes::findOne($id); 

        return $this->render('roompage', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    }

protected function findModel($id)
  {
    if (($model = RoomTypes::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

and in roompage.php `<?php echo Html::encode($data->room_type);?>` to display data associated with id from database

roompage.php

```
<!-- Content -->
<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="bordered_block col-md-12 grey_border">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">


                                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <h3 class="title"><?php echo Html::encode($data->room_type);?></h3>

                                    <div class="meta-box clearfix">
                                        <div class="price-box">                                                                                                     
                                            <span class="special-price">$1420.20</span>
                                            <del class="old-price">$1607.96</del>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>


                                    <p>Single Rooms provide a space of 30-40m², offering a comfortable stay for one guest. </p>


                                    <div class="add-to-box">
                                        <div class="add-to-cart">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control qty" title="Qty" value="1" maxlength="12" id="qty" name="qty">
                                            <span class="increase-qty"><i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i></span>
                                            <span class="decrease-qty"><i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="<?php echo Url::to(['site/shopcart']); ?>">
                                        <button class="button btn btn-default" title="Add to Cart" type="button">
                                            <em class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></em>
                                            <span>Add Cart</span>
                                        </button></a>
                                        <a class="link-wishlist btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a>
                                    </div>



                                </div>


                            <hr>



                                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="true">Description</a></li>
                                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Reviews</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                                  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home" aria-labelledBy="home-tab">
                                    <p>Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" aria-labelledBy="profile-tab">


                                </div>


                        </div>
                        <!--Sidebar End-->




                    </div>
                    <!--Row End-->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- Row End -->


    </div>
</div>
<!-- Content End -->
```

Comment: You want show specific room information based on a room id?

Comment: yes it should be based on room id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aassuming that roompage is the action in the site controller with which you want to display the information of a room identified by id

Your ref should be

```
<div class="col-sm-6 masonry-item">
<a href="<?php echo Url::to(['site/view-roompage', 
     'id' =>$row['room_id']]); ?>" class="product_item text-center">
```

Assuming the controller is site
In you controller you need a new action

```
public function actionViewRoompage($room_id)
{
    return $this->render('view-roompage', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($room_id),
    ]);
}



  protected function findModel($room_id)
  {
    if (($model = Room::findOne($romm_id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

and  then you need a view-rooompage view in your   views/site

in view-roompage.php  you can show the data related tou yuor room ..

If you have the problem with `findOne($room_id)` try with

```
 $data = RoomTypes::find()->where(['room_id' => $room_di])->one();
```

and for the last minor question a suggest you this way

```
     $modelForRate = RoomTypes::find()->where(['room_type' => $model->room_type])->all();

     foreach($modelForRate as $key =>$value){
         $actRate = value->rate

     }
```

Comment: ` public function actionRoompage($id)
    {
        
        return $this->render('roompage');
    }` I have only this in my site controller

Comment: how can you identify a room over another? ... otherwise how you think you can see the information of a room?

Comment: using room id... saw in some tutorials passing id in to url and then using $_GET[] will fetech data from DB for the particular id.. but not getting expected result

Comment: `public function actionRoompage($id) { return $this->render('roompage'); }` this is what I have dont know how to proceed further

Comment: You shoudl have a model related to you room .. and for this model you ,  among others, should should have a view action based on id ... normally this is the code scaffolding for yii2 ..otherwise please explain me your coding contest..

Comment: Yes I have model for room but its for backend for the admin to create room which will show on frontend. which will show by above code in question. 
I dont know how to approach this problem really confused

Comment: Ok then yuo have model and action create/update/delete/view in backedn ...now you need some action in forntend  ... ten minutes and i  post an  updated version  of the answer .

Comment: getting error `Undefined index: id` at `<?php echo Url::to(['site/view-roompage', 
     'id' =>$row['id']]); ?>`

Comment: Have you a field named id in your row / data / room  model ?

Comment: there is `id` in model but not row

Comment: the error in your prevoius  comment seems you haven't ,, check if is 'ID' or  'Id'  be sure you have a field named id and check if you  popolate $data with this field also ..

Comment: I have changed my controller to this public function `actionView($id)
    {
        $searchModel = new RoomTypesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $data = RoomTypes::findOne($id); 
        
        return $this->render('roompage', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    }` and in roompage.php `<?php echo Html::encode($data->room_type);?>` did this

Comment: @Saurabh please update your question with the code ...because in comment is not easy to read the code  ..

Comment: OK .. the controller action seems right but you have an  error `undefined-index `  wher you permform the while loop in you roomcataloge or is solved .. please confirm ..

Comment: there is only one foreach loop in `roomcataloge.php` as mentioned in question there is no while loop

Comment: Ok is a foreach ... but you have the error .. or not .. in this foreach?

Comment: there is no error in `roomcataloge.php` when I click on one of the rooms it should open `roompage.php` while opening `roompage.php` im getting error `Missing required parameters: id`

Comment: You don't use model in you view   so you can comment the first row in render   'model' => $this->findModel($id),

Comment: Are you sure you have a proper id in Url::to(['site/view-roompage', 
     'id' =>$row['id']])   try var_dump($row['id']) this field must containt a valid room id an must not be empty

Comment: You are using prettyUrl or not?

Comment: have you checked the result of var_dump($row['id'])...?

Comment: getting error `Undefined index: id` at `<?php echo Url::to(['site/roompage', 'id' =>$row['id']]); ?>`

Comment: Then i asked a few comment before if there is this error ... then this mean you don't have a field named id in your $row alias in your model ...managed by $data ..

Comment: here the result of var_dump($row['room_id']) `string(3) "100" string(3) "200" string(3) "300"`

Comment: now im able to go on roompage.php with room_id in URL but not able to get the data from database getting error `Trying to get property of non-object` at  `<?php echo Html::encode($data->room_type);?>`

Comment: then  room_id is not id  ... i have update the answer .. you provide to update your code with the proper field name .. like in my answer .. (room_id instead of id)

Comment: foe getting the data form db you need  $data = RoomTypes::findOne($room_id);

Comment: im really sorry i was thinking to call via auto incremented id from database.. 
still getting this error `Missing required parameters: room_id` I did all the changes you were mentioned

Comment: You must update with room_id also the <?php echo Url::to(['site/roompage', room_'id' =>$row['id']]); ?>   .. i have update the answer ..

Comment: showing error `The requested page does not exist.` page has to create dynamically

Comment: Have you commented / delete the   'model' => $this->findModel($id),  in render calling ?

Comment: yes id did that after that its showing error `Trying to get property of non-object`  at `<?php echo Html::encode($data->room_type);?>`

Comment: This mean you don't have a RoomTypes for the room_id you have setted ... are you sure is the RoomTypes the corrct model for showing the room info?

Comment: yes its correct `RoomTypes` model has `room_id` and all other room related information

Comment: then could be you don't have this info fo the room_id selected .. check you  value in db .. please ..

Comment: it has all the details in db as well

Comment: For some reason  ... the RoomTypes::findOne($room_id);  don't return the model you need ... the only reason i know is the value in $room_id and the value in db don't match ... could be a string and an integer ?

Comment: in db `room_id  int(5)`

Comment: this for Room_types and  ... in the RoomCatalouge ?

Comment: there is nothing for `RoomCatalouge` its just a page get all the rooms, result for `var_dump($room_id) in actionRoompage` `Undefined variable: room_id`

Comment: solved with this `$data = RoomTypes::find()->where(['room_id' => $room_id])->one();`

Comment: .... This mean avoid the use of findOne(...) .. well... please mark my answer as accepted and as usefull

Comment: sure.. i have one more small  query, i think iit should not asked as separate question regarding mysql WHERE clause.. I just need to use `$mode->room_name` in WHERE what is the syntax for it? i did                 `->where('room_type = $model->room_name'])`

Comment: you need the var $model->room_type instead of $model->room_id? but  how you obtain room_type   ... you have only  room_id ...

Comment: `$rate = (new yii\db\Query())
                            ->select(['rate'])
                            ->from('room_types')
                            ->where('room_type = $model->room_type'])
                            ->all();`
this the query, im not getting `room_type` result i.e AC,DELUXE etc  is there any syntax error at WHERE?

Comment: I have update the answer with a suggestion  in your code the $model->room_type is inside single quotes

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be difficult. If you have room controller just make another action called `roomDetails()`. Within the a tag create an url that will point to that action and as a parameter send room id. In the action use that argument to get room details from sql via User model and send room details as json, or if you want to render another full view or partial you can send necessary info to the view via `$this->render('roomDetailsPartial', array('roomDetail' => $roomDetailsFromSql))`

You didn't specify what you tried so I can't add code to help you.

Comment: `public function actionRoompage($id) { return $this->render('roompage'); }`- I have only this in my site controller

Comment: How are you getting rooms to you roompage if you are not sending anything to the roompage view? Do you have an actionRoompageCatalogue() or similar?

Comment: Im getting all rooms by above mentioned code, im clueless to get information by room id on roompage from roomcatalogue. 
PS: roompage.php is a template page for all rooms